# Grammatical function of “voller”

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In a test I found the phrase

> Sie ist voller Licht

which meant (it was said) *she is full of light*. I do not undestand *voller* in this context. Pons says it is an *Inv. adj.*, which, in fact, adds to my confusion. Langenscheidt writes *voll(er)* with no indication about the use or not of the *er* ending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voll(er) in this case means "voll von" (full of). The -er is entirely optional, "Sie ist voll Licht" und "Sie ist voller Licht" are identical in meaning. Thus the lack of indication in the Langenscheidt, there is no rule. In this specific case, "voller Licht" is used because "voll Licht" is hard to pronounce because of the adjacent-but-distinct "l"-sounds.

According to both me and the Duden, it's a preposition.

Comment: Präposition klingt in der Tat am sinnvollsten. Es gibt eine sehr eingehende linguistische Untersuchung des Wortes, die zu dem Schluss kommt, dass es ein Unikat ist... auf jeden Fall lesenswert (sind nur Slides, also kein Volltext :)     @EnriqueVasini ... https://www.linguistik.hu-berlin.de/institut/professuren/korpuslinguistik/lehre/alte_jahrgaenge/wise-1213/ko_5220013_dateien/voller_foko

Comment: Danke, das war interessant!